# How to extract positive and negative integers from a string and store it in a list with Python?

Tags: python

## Example Input:

```
'hi6 my name is-34 have you seen96?'
```

## Example Output:

```
[6, -34, 96]
```

I have tried:

```
def extractor(string):
      list1 = [n for n in string if n.isnumber()]
      print(list1)
```

I want to extract even those integers, which are concatenated with some character too.

Comment: "I also tried to use a more complex program, with multiple methods, if, range etc. but nothing." We can only tell you what went wrong with those approaches if you show them. Alternately: did you try to use a search engine to look for existing approaches? For example, you could try putting `python find numbers in string` [into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+find+numbers+in+string), which is how I found the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward would be using regular expressions:

```
import re

def extractor(string):
    return [int(s) for s in re.findall(r"-?\d+", string)]
    # return [*map(int, re.findall(r"-?\d+", string))]

extractor("hi6 my name is-34 have you seen96?")
# [6, -34, 96]
```

`-?`: an optional `"-"`
`\d+`: one or more digits

Documentation:

- [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by user2390182, you can use Regex(Regular Expressions) for solving this problem.
Adding to it, more straightforward regex will be as follows:

```
import re
def Extract_Numbers(Str): return re.findall('(-*[0-9]+)', Str)

print(Extract_Numbers("hi6 my name is-34 have you seen96?")) # ['6', '-34', '96']
```

You can also put the import statement inside the function to make it usable across your projects....

```
def Extract_Numbers(Str):
    import re
    return re.findall('(-*[0-9]+)', Str)

print(Extract_Numbers("hi6 my name is-34 have you seen96?")) # ['6', '-34', '96']
```

Comment: Refer to [Python's Regex Lib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for more